# Using data from elasticsearch in Vega

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I am trying to create a custom Kibana visualization using Vega. The data is text based (not number based), and I really just need it to display something like:
POC: Person
Deployment Date: date
Version: version

All of these are found in elasticsearch under the tags pocInd, deployDate, and version, but I don't know how to read that data in? Instead of the hard-code, I want to have it automatically update when elasticsearch updates. What I have is below:

```
 "background": "green",  
            "width": 200,  
            "height": 100,  
            "padding": 10,  
            "autosize": { "type": "pad"},  
            "data":[  
                {  
                    "name": "table",  
                    "values": [
                    {"label": "POC", "value": "Kyle"},   
                    {"label": "Version", "value": "0.17"}   
                    {"label": "Deploy Date", "value": "0.17"}   
                    ],

              }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of an Elasticsearch question - you need to construct an elastic search query that will return the data you need in a single (preferably) object. Take a look at [my blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/custom-vega-visualizations-in-kibana) about getting started with Vega - see the simple ES query and the indicator example (2nd) - it shows how to draw simple text from ES on a Kibana dashboard.